# DAO Recordset mass update using transactions(excel)

Tags: excel, vba, transactions, dao, recordset

I am trying to export records on mass from a DAO transaction started in an Excel Form using VBA to an Access table yet when I hit commit on the below code nothing is exporting, it must be close but I don't understand why my transaction is empty? If I move ws.committrans to the same button click event as where I start the transaction everything works fine but then that is a single update I want to use transactions for updating multiple records at once.

```
Public db As DAO.Database
Public rs As DAO.Recordset
Public ws As DAO.Workspace

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim val1 As String
Dim val2 As String
Dim val3 As String
Dim val4 As String
Dim val5 As String
Dim val6 As String

Set ws = DBEngine(0)
Set db = ws.OpenDatabase("Database8")
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("test")



val1 = Me.TextBox1.Value
val2 = Me.TextBox2.Value
val3 = Me.TextBox3.Value
val4 = Me.TextBox4.Value
val5 = Me.TextBox5.Value
val6 = Me.TextBox6.Value

ws.BeginTrans

With rs
.AddNew
!col1 = val1
!col2 = val2
!col3 = val3
!col4 = val4
!col5 = val5
!col6 = val6
.Update
End With


Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
Me.TextBox2.Value = ""
Me.TextBox3.Value = ""
Me.TextBox4.Value = ""
Me.TextBox5.Value = ""
Me.TextBox6.Value = ""




End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

ws.CommitTrans

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you write `.Execute` before the `End With` line ? (Just guessing here) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197654.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code to start the transaction when the user form activates and finish it when the commit button is click works like a dream now.

Comment: Other issue I had was then tying the transaction commit to the workbook save event rather than a form button click event. By moving the code out of the form itself and creating a module with callable functions I was able to implement that